# How to properly setup a private webpagetest instance with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webpagetest

I'm trying to setup a private webpagetest instance with AWS. I succeed to have a running webpagetest server, but I'm struggling with agents and autoscaling. To keep things simples, I would like to always have one running agent. All my settings will use the **eu-west-1** region.

Here are all the steps I did to setup everything, thanks to [this guide](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/docs/EC2/Server%20AMI.md) :

- create a T2 medium instance based on the official WPT AMI server (**ami-9978f6ee**)
- create one "wpt" user with access key in IAM
- create 2 security groups : 1 for the wpt server and 1 for the wpt agent, so they'll be able to communicate
- customize **settings.ini** in order to always have 1 running agent with AWS specific settings related to my region

Here are my custom settings in **settings.ini** :

```
EC2.eu-west-1-linux.min=1
EC2.eu-west-1-linux.max=1

ec2_locations=1
ec2=1
ec2_key=*****
ec2_secret=*****
ec2_instance_size=c4.large
EC2.default=eu-west-1
EC2.eu-west-1.securityGroup=*****
EC2.eu-west-1.subnetId=*****
```

First of all, I don't see **eu-west-1-linux** in the wpt user interface inside the location dropdown (looks like locations are not updated until I run 1 test).
Then even if I succeed to have a running agent, I get random issues like test taking ages, or test "stuck" forever, or even loosing connection between wpt server and agent (after checking **http://mywebpagetest/getTesters.php?f=html**).

I think there are a lot of people using WPT with AWS, but I don't think I'm the only one struggling with AWS integration, so if someone has a similar architecture or feedback using, it would be really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to a misconfiguration of the agent's security group. It's not clear which ports Webpagetest agent needs to be able to communicate with Webpagetest server.

So, as a quick fix, I've just opened all incoming TCP ports between my webpagetest agent and my webpagetest server.